# Excel VBA copy multiple worksheets from a Source File to Production file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a daily process with Excel VBA to copy 6 worksheets  from the Source File And create the copy in the Prod File and replace the old same name worksheets with the same name.This will become a “daily repetitive process” where I need to copy the 6 worksheets from the Source File to the Prod File. The worksheets are name the same in both files and want to keep the same worksheet names because I have formulas feeding the Prod File - Main Report.

I am not sure what would be the most Efficient and Effective method to either first Delete the prior worksheets from the Prod File and then copy the current worksheet to the Prod File.

Or

Copy the Source File worksheets to the Prod File, which will create a copy with the number 2, delete the prior worksheet and remove the 2 from the current worksheet name.

Like always I am grateful for this site where solutions are always found.

Here is the Process:

From Source File - I want to Copy the following Worksheets:

*File Name, Sheet Name and Date convention*:

Source FileName: CM Prism MTD ROR MMDDYYYY.xlsx

Worksheets:

- Active Globally
- Active USRR
- Active Indices
- MACO
- Quantile
- HY

To Prod File – Worksheets name will stay the same and Replace the prior worksheet.

*File Name, Sheet Name and Date convention*

Prod FileName: CM Composite MTD as of MM.DD.xlsm

Worksheets:

- Active Globally
- Active USRR
- Active Indices
- MACO
- Quantile
- HY

Also the Source File worksheets has the Valuation Date on Cell “D4” as “09-Oct—2015”, where I would like to add a “valuation date check” to make sure that the worksheets  being copy from the Source file to the Prod file has the same Valuation Date as the Prod File on Cell “D6” as “10/09/2015”.
So if the valuation dates are the same copy to Prod file if not don’t copy it.
The goal is to add any ALERTS or Triggers that is not for Valuation Date.

This is what I have:

```
Sub copyNreplaceWorksheets()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim DpathSource As String
Dim DpathProd As String
Dim FolderName As String
Dim FileNameSource As String
Dim FileNameProd As String
Dim HolidayList
Dim RptDateSource As Date
Dim RptDateProd As Date

Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbProd As Workbook
Dim shtToCopy As Worksheet


Set HolidayList = Range("I77:I86")

''****Set the Report File Date*****
'''Source File: CM Prism MTD ROR MMDDYYYY.xlsx
RptDateSource = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now(), -1, HolidayList), "mmddyyyy")

'''Prod File: CM Composite MTD as of MMDD.xlsm
RptDateProd = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now(), -1, HolidayList), "mm.dd")

'''****Set the File Name*****
'''Source File: CM Prism MTD ROR MMDDYYYY.xlsx
FileNameSource = "CM Prism MTD ROR" & RptDateSource & ".xlsx"

'''Prod File: Aladdin Composite MTD as of MMDD.xlsm
FileNameProd = "CM Composite MTD as of" & RptDateProd & ".xlsm"

'''****Set the Directory Path****
DpathSource = "U:\Performance\CM Performance\" & FileNameSource & ""
DpathProd = "U:\Performance\ROR calculations\2015\Daily Returns\" & FileNameProd & ""


Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("DpathSource")
Set wkbProd = Workbooks.Open("DpathProd")
Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Active US")
shtToCopy.copy wkbProd.Sheets("Active US")

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think deleting the prior sheet, if it exists, will be more logical and easier to interpret in the future.  Use a function like so:

```
Sub DeleteSheet(fromWorkbook as Workbook, sheetName as String)
    'Deletes a named sheet from a workbook
    '  error would occur if the sheet doesn't exist (subscript out of range)
    '  which is ignored by Resume Next
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    fromWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Then, in your code where you need to make the copy, do:

```
Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Active US")
Call DeleteSheet(wkbProd, "Active US")
shtToCopy.copy wkbProd.Sheets(wkbProd.Sheets.Count)
```

You'll want to remove the double quotes here:

```
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(DpathSource)
Set wkbProd = Workbooks.Open(DpathProd)
```

Comment: Thanks David for the suggestion. My code seem very long is there a way to concise it with all the Dim for the Source File and Prod File.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code,  it's pretty concise already. You can declare multiple vars on a single line, but I don't like to do that,  e.g., `Dim FileNameSource$, FileNameProd$` could go on one line.

Comment: David thank you for the correction. I was having diffulties running it. I want to concise the codes to a few lines, is too clutter. Thanks once again.

Comment: Cheers. Do consider up voting or accepting the answer if it's helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks David. It now works. thanks a lot for the suggestions and corrections

Comment: David, one more question. I added the shtToCopy.copy to ActiveWB.Sheets (thisworkbook.sheets.count) , now I want to copy 6  sheets from wkbSource to activeWB. how do I add the code to copy all 6 consecutively.

Comment: Trying to use the For Each, Next but is not coming up right. any light on this issues is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This all is starting to sound like a separate/new question, while it may be related to this code, it should probably be asked as a new question. Also, in accordance with standard etiquette here, if the above answer has solved your original question, you're encouraged to upvote or "accept" it...

Comment: David , I have been using this site for a while from time to time, and finally figure it out I have to  press the up/down arrows. Thank you once again.